# I can't delete Data in my Sqlite Database

Tags: android, sqlite

In my app, I declared my '_id' as string (because my ID includes dashes ('-') ).

Here's my code:

```
    /**
     * Database creation SQL statement
     */
    private static final String DATABASE_CREATE =
            "create table " + DATABASE_TABLE + " ("
                    + KEY_ImagePathID + " text not null, "
                    + KEY_ImagePath + " text not null);";
```

Now In my adapter class I have the following code to delete data:

```
public void delete_Pic_byID(String id){
        mDb.delete(DATABASE_TABLE, KEY_ImagePathID+"="+id, null);

    }
```

The problem now is I cant delete a data when it contains other character aside from numeric characters. But when the ID is numeric, it works perfectly. I'm new to android development and I hope you can help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You missed single quote,So change

```
  mDb.delete(DATABASE_TABLE, KEY_ImagePathID+"="+id, null);
```

to

```
  mDb.delete(DATABASE_TABLE, KEY_ImagePathID+"='"+id + "'", null);
```

Recommanded solution is to use **parameterized query** as

```
mDb.delete(DATABASE_TABLE, KEY_ImagePathID + " = ?",new String[] { id });
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick response! I've been trying to figure this out for hours! You're a life Saver. :)

Comment: I'll accept this as the answer after 10 minutes. :)

Comment: @DEADPOOL happy to help,try to use **recommended solution**.